# Problems linking a button with my picker view answers

Tags: ios, uipickerview

im using a basic picker view in my application, the answer of that picker view is reflected in a label, everything great from there; but I want to link one button to every answer in the picker view so that way when you choose something in the picker view yo can go to an other window and if you choose something else you can go to another window.
For example, if you select 'New York' then press the button and go to the NY window.
And if you choose 'San Francisco' pressing the button will get you to San Francisco's window.

Hope someone have an answer, im really stuck in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code - there is no generic solution for this kind of "problems"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, then the following should be correct.

You have a label you are setting to the value received from the picker. Then the user clicks a button and is taken to the corresponding screen in the app. You only have one button that will take the user to what they picked in the picker.

If this is correct, then I would put an if or switch statement into your button press code that checks the text value for your label, then presents or segues into the appropriate screen.

On button click
If label text == option 1
Seque to screen 1
Else if .... Continue though all your options

If you don't want the label in your final design then just save a string with the value you want to compare to.

If you want multiple buttons to control where to go then that is even easier unless you want the buttons to be dynamic in which case this is much more work and seems unnecessary to me given the ease of the first scenario.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i need, but i mentioned the label just to give you an image, but the level it just for design.
Could you please send me the codes for what you said?
Thanks

Comment: This forum isn't for doing your work, if you have code that isn't working we can help fix it, but me writing an entire function out when you have the pseudo code spelled out is not what this site is for. I'll update the answer with a little more clarity.